# Unable to rename the last file of the directory using loop

Tags: python, windows, rename

I am working on a renaming function which is indexing the video files based on their **Media creation date**. As media creation date is not the file metadata, I am using the **win32com.propsys** module it works completely as expected till the last element of the `FILES` list but goes into loop for the remaining one file. I am unable to catch the issue. It would be really grateful to have positive suggestions.

```
import os
import pytz
import datetime
from win32com.propsys import propsys, pscon
os.chdir(r'H:\Study material\Python\practice')
current_path = r'H:\Study material\Python\practice'
files = os.listdir(current_path)
fi = []
li = []
for f in files:
    properties = propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(r'H:\Study material\Python\practice'+'\\'+f )
    d = properties.GetValue(pscon.PKEY_Media_DateEncoded).GetValue()
    fi.append([str(d),f])
fi.sort()
l = [s[1] for s in fi]
for f in files:
    i = l.index(f) + 1
    new_name = str(i)+'-'+ f
    li.append(new_name)
i = 0
for f in files:
    os.rename(f,li[i])
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the last item in sorted file list is a directory (maybe '__pycache__' ?). Try to check if it is really a file:

```
...
for f in files:
    if not os.path.isfile(f):
        print(f'not a file: {f}')
        continue
    properties = propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(
        os.path.join(r'H:\Study material\Python\practice', f) )
    d = properties.GetValue(pscon.PKEY_Media_DateEncoded).GetValue()
    fi.append([str(d), f])
...
```

Or try to print every filename and new name and see if everything is correct:

```
...
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    print(f, 'rename to', li[i])
    os.rename(f, li[i])
```

Comment: The directory contains 7 files... It renames the 6 files but goes in loop for 1 random file out of 7.... The loop goes on for the 2nd last line where the *rename()* is used

Comment: @VishwajeetBhagat there may be hidden files and folders. I've updated my answer.